# UITableView select a row per section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to make a selection like this
[image]

How can I change my

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method to work in accordance with my requirement.

Comment: I tried using this method,
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    // rows in section 0 should not be selectable
    if ( indexPath.section != 1 || indexPath.section !=2)
    {
        if(indexPath.row !=0)
            
        return nil;
       
    }
    
    return indexPath;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's gonna be ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *list;
    NSMutableArray *sectionList;

    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath0;
    int row0;
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath1;
    int row1;
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath2;
    int row2;
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath3;
    int row3;

    NSString *othersString;
    NSString *timeString;
    NSString *pRoomString;
    NSString *parkingString;
    NSString *smokingString;

    NSString *select0;
    NSString *select1;
    NSString *select2;
    NSString *select3;
}
@end
```

This one's ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // initial row by 100;
    row0 = 100;
    row1 = 100;
    row2 = 100;
    row3 = 100;

    // initial strings by @”"
    othersString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    pRoomString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    parkingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    smokingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

    select0 = @"";
    select1 = @"";
    select2 = @"";
    select3 = @"";

    // Get row index
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/rowString.txt"];
    NSData *rowData = [fileManager  contentsAtPath:fileName];
    // From NSData to NSString
    NSString *rowString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rowData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (rowString) {
        // spit row string
        NSArray *rowArray = [rowString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        for (int i=0; i<[rowArray count]; i++) {
            NSString *indexVal = [rowArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([indexVal length] != 0) {
                // set row value
                if (i == 0) {
                    NSString *row0Str = [rowArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    row0 = [row0Str intValue];
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    NSString *row1Str = [rowArray objectAtIndex:1];
                    row1 = [row1Str intValue];
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    NSString *row2Str = [rowArray objectAtIndex:2];
                    row2 = [row2Str intValue];
                }
                if (i == 3) {
                    NSString *row3Str = [rowArray objectAtIndex:3];
                    row3 = [row3Str intValue];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Update the view with current data before it is displayed.
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Initialize the array.
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    sectionList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    // section header
    NSArray *sectionHeaderArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"01",@"02",@"03",@"04", nil];
    NSDictionary *sectionHeaderDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sectionHeaderArray forKey:@"section"];
    [sectionList addObject:sectionHeaderDic];
    // time list
    NSArray *timeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"time 01",@"time 01",@"time 01", nil];
    NSDictionary *timeDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:timeArray forKey:@"time"];
    // private room
    NSArray *pRoomArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"room 01",@"room 02", nil];
    NSDictionary *pRoomDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pRoomArray forKey:@"pRoom"];
    // parking
    NSArray *parkingArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"park 01",@"park 02",@"park 03", nil];
    NSDictionary *parkingDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:parkingArray forKey:@"parking"];
    // smoking
    NSArray *smokingArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"smoke 01",@"smoke 02",@"smoke 03", nil];
    NSDictionary *smokingDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:smokingArray forKey:@"smoking"];
    // add all dictionary to list
    [list addObject:timeDic];
    [list addObject:pRoomDic];
    [list addObject:parkingDic];
    [list addObject:smokingDic];
    // Scroll the table view to the top before it appears
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //Number of section
    return [list count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Get the dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [list objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            // time array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"time"];
            break;
        case 1:
            // pRoom array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"pRoom"];
            break;
        case 2:
            // parking array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"parking"];
            break;
        case 3:
            // smoking array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"smoking"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //Number of rows
    return [array count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Budget";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle;
    }
    //Get the dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array;
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            // time array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"time"];
            if (indexPath.row == row0 ) {
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            // pRoom array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"pRoom"];
            if (indexPath.row == row1) {
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            // parking array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"parking"];
            if (indexPath.row == row2) {
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            // smoking array
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"smoking"];
            if (indexPath.row == row3) {
                cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"index cell");
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *title = nil;
    //Get the dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [sectionList objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"section"];
    title = [array objectAtIndex:section];
    return title;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                row0 = 100;
                timeString = @"";
            }else {
                NSIndexPath *SIndexPath0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row0 inSection:0];
                if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath0 ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath0] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                }
                if (oldIndexPath0 == nil) {
                    oldIndexPath0 = indexPath;
                }
                UITableViewCell *cell2 = nil;
                if (oldIndexPath0 != indexPath) {
                    cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath0];
                }
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                if (cell2) {
                    cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                }
                //Get the dictionary object
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"time"];
                timeString = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                row0 = indexPath.row;
                oldIndexPath0 = nil;
            }
            select0 = @"marked";
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                row1 = 100;
                pRoomString = @"";
            }else {
                NSIndexPath *SIndexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row1 inSection:1];
                if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath1 ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath1] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                }
                if (oldIndexPath1 == nil) {
                    oldIndexPath1 = indexPath;
                }
                UITableViewCell *cell2 = nil;
                if (oldIndexPath1 != indexPath) {
                    cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath1];
                }
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                if (cell2) {
                    cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                }
                //Get the dictionary object
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"pRoom"];
                pRoomString = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                row1 = indexPath.row;
                oldIndexPath1 = nil;
            }
            select1 = @"marked";
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                row2 = 100;
                parkingString = @"";
            }else {
                NSIndexPath *SIndexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row2 inSection:2];
                if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath2 ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath2] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                }
                if (oldIndexPath2 == nil) {
                    oldIndexPath2 = indexPath;
                }
                UITableViewCell *cell2 = nil;
                if (oldIndexPath2 != indexPath) {
                    cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath2];
                }
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                if (cell2) {
                    cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                }
                //Get the dictionary object
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"parking"];
                parkingString = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                row2 = indexPath.row;
                oldIndexPath2 = nil;
            }
            select2 = @"marked";
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                row3 = 100;
                smokingString = @"";
            }else {
                NSIndexPath *SIndexPath3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row3 inSection:3];
                if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath3 ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
                    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:SIndexPath3] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                }
                if (oldIndexPath3 == nil) {
                    oldIndexPath3 = indexPath;
                }
                UITableViewCell *cell2 = nil;
                if (oldIndexPath3 != indexPath) {
                    cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath3];
                }
                cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                if (cell2) {
                    cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                }
                //Get the dictionary object
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"smoking"];
                smokingString = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                row3 = indexPath.row;
                oldIndexPath3 = nil;
            }
            select3 = @"marked";
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Cancle button and add an event handler
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancle"
                                     style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(handleCancle:)];
    // Cancle button and add an event handler
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Use"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(handleUse:)];
}
- (void) handleCancle:(id)sender
{
    // pop the controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void) handleUse:(id)sender{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *fileName;
    // Get row index value
    fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/othersString.txt"];
    NSData *rowValData = [fileManager   contentsAtPath:fileName];
    // From NSData to NSString
    NSString *rowValString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rowValData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *oldTimeString = @"";
    NSString *oldpRoomString = @"";
    NSString *oldParkingString = @"";
    NSString *oldSmokingString = @"";
    if (rowValString) {
        // spit row string
        NSArray *rowValArray = [rowValString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        for (int i=0; i<[rowValArray count]; i++) {
            if ([rowValArray objectAtIndex:i] != @"") {
                // set row value
                if (i == 0 ) {
                    oldTimeString = [rowValArray objectAtIndex:0];
                }
                if (i == 1 ) {
                    oldpRoomString = [rowValArray objectAtIndex:1];
                }
                if (i == 2 ) {
                    oldParkingString = [rowValArray objectAtIndex:2];
                }
                if (i == 3) {
                    oldSmokingString = [rowValArray objectAtIndex:3];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (select0 == @"") {
        timeString = oldTimeString;
    }
    if (select1 == @"") {
        pRoomString = oldpRoomString;
    }
    if (select2 == @"") {
        parkingString = oldParkingString;
    }
    if (select3 == @"") {
        smokingString = oldSmokingString;
    }
    // make othersString string
    othersString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@:%@", timeString, pRoomString, parkingString, smokingString];
    // write othersString to othersString.txt file
    fileName= [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/othersString.txt"];
    NSData *othersData = [othersString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:othersData attributes:nil];
    // make row data in string
    NSString *rowString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i:%i", row0,row1,row2,row3];
    // write othersString to othersString.txt file
    fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/rowString.txt"];
    NSData *rowData = [rowString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:rowData attributes:nil];
    // pop the controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [list release];
}
@end
```

Got this stuff from this [post](http://g-bleu.co.jp/blog/media/iphone/from-every-section-of-uitableview-can-select-only-one-cell), as this was in Japanese I changed it. Thanks to the author.

Comment: wayyyy too complicated

Answer (score 3):

Why so complicated? Just deselect all cells of the same section before the user selects a new one.

First allow multiple selection for your UITableView. Then implement this delegate method:

**Swift 3 version:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
{
    for vcip in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? [] {
        if vcip.section == indexPath.section && vcip.item != indexPath.item {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: vcip, animated: false)
        }
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer but it does not facilitate the removing of the accessory checkmark as the OP is looking for. I will expand on LimeRed's answer separately in order to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep a property in your view controller called `selectedRow`, which represents the indexPath of tableview that represents the checked item in a table section.
2. In your view controller's `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, set the `accessoryType` of the `cell` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` if the cell's `indexPath` equals the `selectedRow` indexpath value. Otherwise, set it to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`.
3. In your view controller's `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, set the `selectedRow` value to the `indexPath.row` that is selected, e.g.: `self.selectedRow = indexPath.row`

Comment: Using your ans.. I made my code, which is attached below. Kindly check it.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a good solution.
Use a `NSMutableArray` for storing the selected sections.

```
NSMutableArray *selectedSections; //instance variable

selectedSections= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   //in viewDidLoad

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSNumber *section = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section];
   if([selectedSections containsObject:section]
      return nil;
   else
   {
      [selectedSections addObject:section];
      return indexPath;
   }
}
```

When you deselect a row write the below code there:

```
[selectedSections removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans, One can't update the selection using this. It's like selected once and cant update.

Answer (score 2):

LimeRed has a great answer elsewhere in this thread, but it is not complete. The key issue is that the OP needs to have the accessory checkmark removed. Simply calling `deselectRow` will not remove the checkmark. Per the documentation, `deselectRow` does not call the delegate method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` where the removal of the checkmark code might be located. Therefore you need handle this removal as part of the code that LimeRed wrote.

Here is a more complete implementation that removes the accessory checkmark again based on LimeRed's solution:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
    {
        for path in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []
        {
            if path.section == indexPath.section && path.item != indexPath.item
            {
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path)
                cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
                tableView.deselectRow(at: path, animated: false)
            }
        }

        return indexPath
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

In .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *checkedIndexPath;
```

In .m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 


    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {

        // to check and Uncheck the row
        if(self.checkedIndexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView1
                                            cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
            uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was able to make only one selection through out the available 3 sections. Can't make a selection per a section.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of modifications I have arrived with this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if([section1Rows count] == 0)
    {
        [section1Rows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    else
    {
        [section1Rows removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tabview visibleCells]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        [section1Rows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"%@",section1Rows);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    if([section2Rows count] == 0)
    {
        [section2Rows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    else
    {
        [section2Rows removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tabview visibleCells]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        [section2Rows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"%@",section2Rows);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    if([section3Rows count] == 0)
    {
        [section3Rows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    else
    {
        [section3Rows removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tabview visibleCells]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        [section3Rows addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"%@",section3Rows);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}


}
```

I'll explain the problem in steps,
I have selected a row in 3 sections, If I select a row again in any of the sections... then everything goes haywire. How can I deselect the previously selected row and highlight the then selected row?

Thanks.

Comment: Use this for every section `for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tabview visibleCells]) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }`

Comment: Yeah that piece of code is added in every section, using which it reloads the entire tableView. I want that one to reload only a section which is not possible.

Comment: you want to allow select single row in every section or only single row in all the sections?

Comment: Sorry for the causing the doubt, I want to have single row in every section.